# Emulating display block behaviour

Tags: css, css-float, block, sharepoint-2013

I have HTML like below and all is displaying grand, the problem is that due to a problem with Sharepoint 2013's editor your unable to edit the link text but as soon as I remove `display: block` I can edit the link text, the same happens using `float`.

My question is there a way to emulate the affect of `display: block` where it will span the whole width that is available to it without using display or float?

```
<div class="button">
     <a href="#">Link Text</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one option to make an inline element to be like a block by using `position:absolute` without using display or float.

But I hope absolute positioning doesn't fit your want. Thus, the final conclusion is that you must use display or float property to render it correctly.

If you even use absolute then don't forget to keep `position:relative` to your parent element from which you want to be the element as absolute.

Comment: Same issue occurs with using the position attributes.

Comment: Yeah, I already commented on posted answer, use position relative to your nearest parent element in your case...

Answer (score 0):

You could try `display: inline-block; width: 100%;`. You might need to alter the width to take into account any padding or border you've set.

(In the past I've used an edit mode panel and other tricks, so these hacky styles only apply when the page is being edited.)

SharePoint 2013's editor is *so utterly awesome* isn't it? :-(

Comment: Good point. I misread it thinking @atallon didn't want `display: block;`. The major problem is that SharePoint's WYSIWYG doesn't expect links to be anything other than `inline`. Still, this is SharePoint, which means literally *anything* is worth a try.